# htaccess subdomain redirect to a another directory without changing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a website domain.xxx

There is per location a directory. As example here domain.xxx/location/place

I would like to have the following subdomain place.domain.xxx and display the content of the matching folder.

This works like a charm:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.place.domain.xxx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.xxx/location/place/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^≈
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.xxx/location/place/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But Problem is that when I enter url place.domain.xxx the url in the browser bar gets redirected. I would like to keep the URL in the unchanged place.domain.xxx.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

i am using following code in my site, for redirecting subdomain.domain.com to subdomain folder

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That works but then I would need to change the site structure which would be very work intensive. But thank you very much for the pointer.